# iphone - didSelectRowAtIndexPath: only being called after long press on custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating one table view based application.  I have created a custom table cell for table, that contains 2 labels, 1 image and 1 button. The table view Data source method is working properly. I am using xib for both custom cell and view controller class and i connect delegate and data source to the file's owner. But the problem is when i select the table row, didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not getting fire. As mentioned the only way to fire it is to hold down on the cell for about 3-4 seconds. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks for any pointers...

Here is my table view methods..

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [finalAddonsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NewCustomCell *cell = (NewCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"NewCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    Addons *addons1=[[Addons alloc]init];
    addons1= [finalAddonsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (addons1.data == nil) {
        cell.ivCategory.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blogo.jpg"];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.ivCategory.image=[UIImage imageWithData:addons1.data];
    }

    cell.lblTitle.text = addons1.name;
    if (addons1.price == nil) {
        cell.lblPrice.text = nil;
    }
    else{
        cell.lblPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ rs",addons1.price];
    }
    [cell.button addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(editButtonPressed:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    cell.button.tag=indexPath.row;
    index = indexPath;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"sjcjksbcjksbcfkebscf1234567890");
}
```

One more thing i am getting that if i am using default UITableViewCell instead of custom cell then also my problem is same, delegate method is not getting fire.

Custom cell properties:

[image]  [image]

Comment: Where is the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: Why do you determine it gets fired late? Are you absolutely sure it takes 3-4 seconds or does the action you expect only occur then? Add an NSLog or breakpoint to the first line of didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Also - what is the size of the button in the cell?

Comment: @nikhitaI am updating my question with didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: if you are pushing a view Controller from **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**  i think nextViewcontroller load some data from web-service. thays why that pushing a viewcontroller take 3_4 second and you thought didSelectRowAtIndexPath selecting cell take some time.

Comment: @StavashYes, i put the breakpoint, it is coming in the breakpoint after long press on table row cell.

Comment: @NitinNo i am not pushing any view controller, this table view is added in one UIView, that UIView only i have to make hidden.

Comment: Is there any subview on the custom cell which is consuming touches?

Comment: @AmarNo, i have one UIButton that action i am giving in cellForRowAtIndexPath method & an action is working fine on cell.

Comment: How about cell highlighting? Does it occur immediately or only after a delay as well? Any active UIGestureRecognizer around?

Comment: @StavashYes, it is highlighting in single click only, but delegate does not fire.

Comment: @StavashThanks bro, i am using gesture reconizer for view controller class, after removing gesture..it is getting fire

Comment: @Anand if it is fire late then delegate is calling for sure...i think problem is in image data...i think it is image which is taking time to load..try disable the else part of  cell.ivCategory.image

Comment: @RaghuThanks, delegate was not firing bcoz of tap gesture...

Comment: You must have used some view over that tableview or any another gesture recognizer in superview of tableview

Answer (score 100, accepted):

same problem happened with me because I have added a tap gesture recogniser over it.
If you have used any gesture recognizer try removing it and check if it causing the problem.

EDIT: Solution as commented by the Ali:
If you have used tap gesture you can use `[tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];`

Comment: @parserThanks,same pblm i had. delegate was not firing bcoz of tap gesture

Comment: Great... you pointed out the reason for the issue.... but what is the solution for this... I have some text fields in the view and I want to dismiss the keyboard on tap. How do I do that ?

Comment: In your tap gesture add this `[tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];`

Comment: Struggling with this issue for several hours! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As others suggested, `[tap setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];` does the trick. 
However, I want to make one thing clear:

If you think that you did not implement tapgesture and are curious about why you had to add your view into the protected views, check out your class because most probably you have inherited some class and that class includes tap gesture recognizer in it.

In my case, I did the following:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)tapProtectedViews
{
    NSMutableArray *views = [super tapProtectedViews];
    [views addObject:self.mTableView];
    return views;
}
```

**Edit for Swift 4+**

Assuming you have a UITapGestureRecognizer instance named tapGesture:

```
func disableTapGesture(){
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
}
```

Or you can:

```
if self.view.gestureRecognizers?.isEmpty == false{
    for recognizer in self.view.gestureRecognizers!{
        self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }
 }
```

Comment: "most probably you have inherited some class and that class includes tap gesture recognizer" - This was the problem for me!

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with a similar issue:

For me, the problem was because my `UITableView` was added to an `UIScrollView` and more specifically to its `contentView`.
It appears that inside the `contentView`, I had to stay press 2-3 sec to fire the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

I moved my TableView to `self.view` instead of `contentView` and it solved the problem!

Comment: Not Exactly, but it Pointed me in the Right Direction ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you will call the method

`[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];`

before Push ViewController or Other Operation. Like

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // 1. manual call this method to deSelect Other Cell
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    // 2. than do other operation
    PushViewController Or Some Animation ....
}
```

that`s solve my problem .

Answer (score 0):

Dear i faced the same problem. When i tapped the cell but didselectrowatindexpath was not called than it was suddenly called when i released the button after pressing it for few seconds.

If you are facing the same issue there must be a 
 1. UITapGestureRecognizer that is creating problem for you 
                     or 
 2. a scroll view in which you placed you table view.

Thus you should remove the gesture or the super scroll view in which your table view is placed

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom gesture object on your view, check `override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool` delegate. Compare custom gesture with sender gesture, If its not custom gesture object, pass it to the the super. So system gestures/taps won't get blocked.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure about this, but `Delays Content Touches` might have something to do with it.

Comment: In the first screenshot you posted, in the `ScrollView` section, the property `Delays Content Touches` is enabled. Try disabling it, and testing it.