# iOS UITableViewCell Have To Hold A Long Press To Select Item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So this is driving me nuts, whenever I tap an item in my UITableView it does nothing, but when i press and hold the UITableViewCell after about 3-5 seconds it decides to move forward and do what I want.. any thoughts why this might be happening?

Here's my code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    _cell = [_arrayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _cell = nil;
     static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";
    _cell = (CustomWidget *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
    if (_cell == nil) {
        _cell = [[CustomWidget alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier title:[_arrayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] subTitle:@"Custom subtitle"];
    }

    _cell.textLabel.text = [_arrayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _cell.textLabel.hidden = YES;
    return _cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return _arrayItems.count;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    _passedInPageTitle = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    [self openDetailPage];
}
```

Comment: Maybe your CustomWidget has a UIButton or something similar which became firstResponder and receiving all those events? Also, after didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I usually call `  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` to make sure it is getting deselected.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, does it get hit the second you tap an item or after 3-5 seconds?  Unrelated, what are you accomplishing with the first two lines of cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Also, directly calling cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't very kosher.  You should retrieve information you need from your model (_arrayItems) using the indexPath. For all you know, calling that could be creating an entirely new cell from memory.

Comment: Did you remember to set your tableview's delegate to the class that's implementing tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:? And does this class declare that it implements UITableViewDelegate?

Comment: You inspired me to create a StackOverflow question I can reference from now on ;): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510288/is-calling-cellforrowatindexpath-ever-practical/20510328?noredirect=1#20510328

Comment: Make sure that the table doesn't have delaysContentTouches set to YES.

Comment: 1. chuthan20 I did have a button there and removed it and I'm still getting the same result.

2. chuthan20 Thanks for the heads up I've added [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

3. ErikKerber I put a break point there and found that it does not get called the moment I touch the tableviewcell item.

4. ErikKerber With the first two lines I'm passing in an array of items i've created to test with.

5. ErikKerber Sorry, still somewhat of a noob, could you elaborate?

Comment: 6. AlexShepard Yeah, I checked it and in the header file I'm telling the UIView (file containing the tableview and a related UIView for searching) to use  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> and then where the tableView is created I'm assigning the datasource and delegate.

7. rdelmar I've set the delaysContentTouches set to NO and still the same result. :(

Thank you for the time spent on this, I'll keep trying to solve this one off issue :)

Comment: Try changing the code you have in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. You shouldn't get the string from the cell, you should get it with _arrayItems[indexPath.row]. So delete that first line,and change the right side of the second line to what I wrote above. I don't know if this will fix your problem, but you should do it this way anyway -- cells are for displaying data, not for providing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18159463/374873) - I had a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the `UITableView`'s parent view, which was capturing the tap.