# Is calling cellForRowAtIndexPath: ever practical?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've seen many *many* developers when implementing a `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` directly call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to either:

1) Retrieve the cell to grab a model element that they stored within
    the cell:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    int secretCode = cell.secretCode;
    LaunchMissileViewController *vc = [[LaunchMissileViewController alloc] initWithSecretCode:secretCode];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc];
}
```

2) Attempt to style the cell (this has clear problems, but seems very common):

```
MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
// or [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPat:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Is it safe to make the blanket statement that "only the framework should *ever* call `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`"? Or is there a practical reason one might ever call it themselves?

Comment: It's an inefficient way to fetch a value, but calling it for that may be merited, for it's simplicity (ie, avoiding additional code to separately fetch data).  I can't see that you should style the cell that way, since cells are deleted and recycled at whim by the system, so any styling would be transitory.

Comment: I can't think of any reason you should ever call it yourself. It's sole purpose is to inform/manage the TableView. If you made a change to a cell, you'd just reload the data. I'm interested if anyone knows otherwise.

Comment: It should be noted that the above calls are to UITableView's version of cellForRowAtIndexPath, not the data source's version.  But I assume that's basically a pass-through if the cell doesn't already exist -- you just benefit from fetching a cached cell if it exists already.  Doesn't make a major difference in the topic of this discussion.

Comment: And I guess this is an appropriate way to access a cell that was selected, etc.  If a cell is selected you may need to access it to change background color or whatever.  The alternative is to do reload rows and cause the cell to be reconstructed.  (You do, obviously, need to separately track it's selected status or whatever, should the cell be reloaded).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally I don't think there are ever good cases to directly call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` directly on the data source.

For case #1 it is simply bad coding. The cell should never contain the data. The data source should have the data so get the data from the actual data source, not the cell.

For case #2 you would only ever need to update a visible cell. And for this you can use the `UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. No need to call the data source for the cell.

I try never to say "never" but it should be an extremely rare case where you have a real need to get the cell by calling the data source method.

Comment: Yep. Sometimes, if you give a cell data, the dequeueReusableCell functionality will cause issues of that data appearing on a different cell (being "reused"). Always use the data source for data.

Answer (score 3):

I will say rmaddy is correct, though I have one case where it is *arguably* practical to use:

If you ever require a **copy** of a UITableViewCell to apply to another view.

(derived from [https://github.com/Ice3SteveFortune/i3-dragndrop](https://github.com/Ice3SteveFortune/i3-dragndrop/blob/master/Classes/I3DragBetweenHelper.m))

```
UIView* cellCopy;

UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSData* viewCopyData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:cell];
cellCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:viewCopyData];

// Maybe to drag-and-drop outside of the UITableViewCell.
[self.otherView addSubview:cellCopy];
```

I want to leave this here as an example of *one of the **few** cases where it is remotely practical to call cellForRowAtIndexPath:*

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving data from the cell makes no sense as the data being inserted into the cell would be known to the developer. The developer can straight away get the data. Another problem, (big one) with this approach is that if that cell is not visible, it would be first generated and then the data retrieved.