# Cell change being applied to multiple cells

Tags: uitableview, swift

When a user clicks on a button inside the cell of my tableView, I want it to change multiple properties of the cell. I assign a the indexPath.row value as the tag value to each cell in a different class. Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func upvote(sender: AnyObject) {

let row = sender.tag
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRom: row, in Section: 0)
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as FeedPageTableViewCell

cell.upVote.setImage("green", forState: .Normal)

}
```

**The problem is that though it works on the cell I click on, it also applies to each cell 5 rows below that.**

Comment: why are you not using table view delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath. It will give you exact cell and you can change the behavior then.

Comment: I am selecting a button inside the cell, not the cell itself. How would I use didSelectRowAtIndexPath for an IBAction?

Comment: more support of my answer here, and a comment that describes a similar problem to what you're experiencing http://stackoverflow.com/a/20510328/1241782

Answer (score 1):

It isn't proper to update a `UITableViewCell` by retrieving it from the `UITableView` like that. I do not think this does what you're expecting:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as FeedPageTableViewCell
cell.upVote.setImage("green", forState: .Normal)
```

Instead, you should have some instance array of data that you keep up-to-date. In this case you may have an array of booleans, where the index is the row and the value is whether not it is "upvoted". Then in your `upvote` function you would update the boolean and reload your table/cell to render the appropriate data.

Answer (score 0):

Add Target to the UIButton , Use this Method for the action on button

```
-(void)handeltap:(UIButton*)sender{

CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
NSUInteger lastIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];
```

}

On lastIndex will give the correct index path , Try and if not happens let me know.

Comment: Could you write it in swift please? Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisJones : Sorry dude . No time . just change the syntax thats all. Nothing complex.

Comment: Still applies the change to multiple cells :(. Any other ideas?

Comment: In CellforRowatIndex .. Put if condition to check .

Comment: if condition to check what?