# Repeating values in Stepper inside TableViewCell when scrolling

Tags: xcode, swift, tableview

Stepper problem when cells need scroll.

My_TableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class My_TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var My_Label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var My_Label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var My_Stepper: UIStepper!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

...
```

My_TableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

var My_Ids = ["C01","C02","C03","C04","C05","C06","C07","C08","C09","C10"]
var My_Values = ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]

class My_TableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBAction func My_Stepper(sender: AnyObject) {

    let point = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)!
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! My_TableViewCell
    cell.My_Label2.text = "\(Int(cell.My_Stepper.value))"

}

...

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return My_Ids.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell =
    self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        "My_TableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        as! My_TableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.My_Label1.text = My_Ids[row]
    cell.My_Label2.text = "\(Int(cell.My_Stepper.value))"
    return cell
}

...
```

When all cells fit in a "page" the Stepper works well but if the cells are resized and you need scroll the tableview the values are repeated in other cells.

If you alter the value on the cells C06 and C07 this will to reflect C01 and C02 cells and vice-versa.

[Please view this image showing the snapshots with the errors](http://www.berka.com.br/tableviewsteppererror.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewController` intentionally reuses cells as an optimization. You need to clear the old cell settings as part of your solution. Add a `prepareForReuse` method to your `My_TableViewCell` class. 
You do this:

```
- (void) prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    // clear previous cell settings
}
```

Additional Notes:

- recommend against calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` directly. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510288/is-calling-cellforrowatindexpath-ever-practical).
- recommend you use Pascal casing for class names: Use `MyTableViewCell` instead of `My_TableViewCell`.

Comment: Thank you. I was using stepper to store values. Now I added the prepareForReuse function to zero it and I limited the stepper in -1 and +1,  then I add its value each time it is changed to one array that store the result.

Comment: Thank you also for other recommendations. I will follow them.